# iPhone - Get Facebook user session from Facebook Connect app

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication

I am using Facebook connect SDK in my application. 
It works fine, but I don't know how to use the already active session of the user from the Facebook Connect app on Iphone.

If the user is already logged in using the native Facebook app, how can I use this session and skip the in app log in process?

Thanks a lot,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps are sandboxed -- you can't get this information.  Even if it were technically possible, Apple would reject the app if you did it.